# How to create a Django Virtual Environment offline?

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am trying to build a Django virtual environment on my PC that is not connected to Internet. I have **Miniconda** installed on the PC.
When I run this command:

```
conda create --name MyDjangoEnv django
```

I get an error "Conda http error" and it says that I cannot connect to https://www.anaconda.com.
Do i need to download any packages from the Internet to make it work?

Comment: I think you should try with virtualenv by installing pip install virtualenv, then create env by using virtualenv my_name. And after it activate your virtualenv and then installs django in it. Let me know if you want all steps. I will post it in answer

Comment: Yes, kindly give the steps. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need an internet connection in order to download any package. I think virtualenv has not been installed on your system. First, install it then try to create the env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Open your command prompt and Install virtualenv using

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Step 2: Create a virtualenv for your django application

```
virtualenv your_virtual_env_name
```

Step 3: Activate your virtualenv using

```
your_virtual_env_name\Scripts\activate
```

Step 4: Install Django

```
pip install Django
```

After this, you can follow this [to work on Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/)

Comment: Kindly, let me know if you need further help. Also, accept my answer as accepted if it addresses your problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to install python packages into your pc using miniconda, connection is needed, because you need to download it and then install.

If you need to install an additional package like Django, I suggest to proceed in this way:

**Step1:** create a new conda virtualenv with the following command:

```
conda create --name MyDjangoEnv
```

If you need to use a specific Python version use the following command:

```
conda create --name MyDjangoEnv python=x.y
```

where x.y is for example 3.5

**Step2:** activate the enviroment just created with the following command:

```
conda activate MyDjangoEnv
```

**Step3:** Install Django with the following command:

```
conda install django
```

**Step4:** Try to run the runserver and if are missing other package you can install them with command:

```
conda install <package>
```